# chain code invoke error at private data sample for Fabric v1.4

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I follow the instruction at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private_data_tutorial.html steps by steps but have error like this "Error: error parsing transient string: invalid character '\n' in string literal - proposal response: " at chain code invoke. Is there anyone have the same issue? Would you please advise how to fix it. Many thanks!

I follow the instruction at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private_data_tutorial.html steps by steps but have error at chain code invoke

The return is "Error: error parsing transient string: invalid character '\n' in string literal - proposal response: "

I issue invoke command bellow:
export MARBLE=$(echo -n "{\"name\":\"marble1\",\"color\":\"blue\",\"size\":35,\"owner\":\"tom\",\"price\":99}" | base64)
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n marblesp -c '{"Args":["initMarble"]}'  --transient "{\"marble\":\"$MARBLE\"}"

export MARBLE=$(echo -n "{\"name\":\"marble1\",\"color\":\"blue\",\"size\":35,\"owner\":\"tom\",\"price\":99}" | base64)
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n marblesp -c '{"Args":["initMarble"]}'  --transient "{\"marble\":\"$MARBLE\"}"

expect :
[chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery->INFO 001 Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200

Actual result :
"Error: error parsing transient string: invalid character '\n' in string literal - proposal response: "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May i ask which machine are you using? and check if **tr -d \n** is present while

> export MARBLE=$(echo -n "{\"name\":\"marble1\",\"color\":\"blue\",\"size\":35,\"owner\":\"tom\",\"price\":99}" | base64 | **tr -d \n**)

given

> tr command strips off the problematic newline characters that linux base64 command adds.

if the problem still occurs you can refer to 
[How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)
and try

> tr -d '\n'

or

> tr --delete '\n'

Comment: Hello Harshit, thanks for your prompt reply. I use Ubuntu 16.04. It works after I add tr -d '\n'.
The correct command is:
"export MARBLE=$(echo -n "{\"name\":\"marble1\",\"color\":\"blue\",\"size\":35,\"owner\":\"tom\",\"price\":99}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')
Thanks!

Comment: That's great :)

Answer (score 1):

The Fabric [private data tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private_data_tutorial.html#store-private-data) has been updated to indicate the newlines should be stripped away with `tr -d \\n` like this:

```
export MARBLE=$(echo -n "{\"name\":\"marble1\",\"color\":\"blue\",\"size\":35,\"owner\":\"tom\",\"price\":99}" | base64 | tr -d \\n)
```